# Hide laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, exception, error-handling

Tried many code samples and examples from documentation from other sites and none of them worked or i dont understand how to use it. how get rid of this error?Well it looks not nice and my clients or users who can try to guess route can see this.Would be great to change this to 404 or custom blade. Using laravel 8.

[image: h]

route code

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'domain.domain.com'], function()
{       
  Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@index')->name('view.klientas');
  Route::post('/check', 'App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@check')->name('check')->middleware('checknamemail');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

how to use this route:

```
Route::fallback(function () {
  abort(404);
});
```

Only for one route group not for all routes in web api?

Comment: Show the code of route file.

Comment: Added to post routes to that domain

Comment: The issue is "Route expect the method POST and it is calling using GET method".

Comment: Have you call the route 'check' using POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `debug` key to `false` in your `.env` file during the production to hide any debug error messages and instead show a user readable error message to the user.

Find the `.env` file in the root folder of your Laravel project folder, open it with an editor and set the `debug=false` and save it.

Also, run `php artisan config:clear` to clear the configuration cache and reload all the values from the .env file.

Comment: tried this one. Doesn't work the same error code show up.

Comment: You need to also call ``php artisan config:clear`` in your terminal to clear the .env cached data

Answer (score 1):

in the web.php at the bottom put the callback function

[Fallback Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes)

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    abort(404);
});
```

Comment: How can i use this not for all routes but only for one group of 4